# TypeError: config must be a tf.ConfigProto, but got <class 'int'>

Tags: python, tensorflow, openai-gym

the code given below shows some error while running this part of code in the DQN agent .I got this from the github the link is https://github.com/AdrianP-/gym_trading

```
with U.make_session(8):

    act, train, update_target, debug = deepq.build_train(
        make_obs_ph=lambda name: U.BatchInput(env.observation_space.shape, name=name),
        q_func=model,
        num_actions=env.action_space.n,
        optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=5e-4),
    )
```

I got the typeerror :

> TypeError: config must be a tf.ConfigProto, but got <class 'int'>

i think this error is related to tensorflow
please help me to figure out the error

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the interface to `make_session` changed. The first parameter is now `config=`, which is supposed to be a `tensorflow.Config` object. Try changing to

```
    with U.make_session()
```

or

```
    with U.make_session(num_cpu=8)
```

which is possibly what was originally meant.